# Basic input and output in Java

Tags: java, io

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.4 and I am very new to Java and I am trying to get the user to input two numbers (both of them are doubles) and then store them in another variable. I have gone to DOZENS of tutorial sites and they are no good. How can I get basic input and outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primitive example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Print something:");    // printing output
        String text = scanner.nextLine();          // taking input

        System.out.println("You have printed the following text: " + text);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**:
Sorry, missed the point, that you want to take doubles. Here you go:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class TestIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double firstDouble = 0L;
        double secondDouble = 0L;
        while (true) {  // take input (two doubles) until successful
            System.out.println("Print two doubles (press enter after each input):");
            try {
                firstDouble = scanner.nextDouble();
                secondDouble = scanner.nextDouble();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong input. You must print doubles.\n" +
                                   "Depending on your locale, as a decimal separator " +
                                   "use either a comma or a dot.\n");
                scanner.nextLine(); // clearing the buffer with the wrong input
                                    // to avoid infinite loop
                continue;
            }
            break; 
        }
        // Printing the user input (limiting doubles to 3 decimal places)
        System.out.format("You have printed %.3f and %.3f %n", 
                          firstDouble, secondDouble);
    }
}
```

---

Recommended reading:

- the official [Oracle Java
  Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) - it's very informative and easy to understand
- Lesson: [Basic
  I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) (from the above tutorials)

Comment: double d1 = Double.parseDouble(text);

Comment: @sgmart Yeah, there're lots of variations. I just threw some basic example ))

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in)
public static void main (String[] args)
{
double input1, input2; // Declares the double value of input1 and input2
input1 = console.nextDouble(); // User inputs value into input1
input2 = console.nextDouble();

String value1 = "" + input1; // Storing value into a String
String value2 = "" + input2;
// If you want to store it in let's say string.
// Or else i think / int value1 = Integer.parseInt(input1);
// This changes the double value into an Int value
// Something like that.
}
}
```

Not quite sure if that was your question because outputting a value could also be with

```
System.out.println(input1); // This outputs the value of input1 on the screen.
```